# Set formula in Google App Scripts based on variables

Tags: variables, dynamic, scripting, formula

In this code:

```
for(var i = 1 ; i <= lastColumn; i++ ){
    
    labelCell = sheetFaturas.getRange(2,i).getValue(); 

    if (labelCell==="Date"){
      sheet.getRange(3, i, lastRow-2, 1).setBackground("#d9d9d9");
      var formula = sheet.getRange(3,i)+sheet.getRange(6,i);
      sheet.getRange(3, i, lastRow-2, 1).setFormula(formula);
    }
}
```

I am trying to define a formula with variables (in this case "i"). How can I do that? All examples I see are like "=SUM(B5:B7)". This is fine, but admits I already know the cell range. In this case I gotta find it and end up with a variable "i".

Thanks a lot.